# How do I generate new source code in text form in a Scala compiler plugin?

Tags: scala, plugins, compiler-construction

I have just finished the first version of a Java 6 compiler plugin, that automatically generates wrappers (proxy, adapter, delegate, call it what you like) based on an annotation.

Since I am doing mixed Java/Scala projects, I would like to be able to use the same annotation inside my Scala code, and get the same generated code (except of course in Scala). That basically means starting from scratch.

What I would like to do, and for which I haven't found an example yet, is how do I generate the code inside a Scala compiler plugin in the same way as in the Java compiler plugin. That is, I match/find where my annotation is used, get the AST for the annotated interface, and then *ask the API to give me a Stream/Writer in which I output the generated Scala source code, using String manipulation*.

That last part is what I could not find. So how do I tell the API to create a new Scala source file, and give me a Stream/Writer/File/Handle, so I can just write in it, and when I'm done, the Scala compiler compiles it, within the same run in which the plugin was invoked?

Why would I want to do that? Firstly, because than both plugins have the same structure, so maintenance is easy. Secondly, I want to open source it, and there is just no way to support every option that anyone would want, so I expect potential users to want to extend the generation with their own code. This will be a lot easier for them if they just have to do some printf(), instead of learning the AST API (this also applies to me).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:**

It can't be done

**Long answer:**

You could conceivably generate your source file and push that through a parser instance within your plugin.  But not in any way that's likely to be of any use to you, because you'd now have a bigger problem to contend with:

In order to grab all the type/name information for generating the delagate/proxy, you'll have to pick up the annotated type's AST after it has run through both the namer and typer phases (which are inseperable).  The catch is that any attempts to call your generated code will already have failed typechecking, the compiler will have thrown an error, and any further bets are off.

Method synthesis *is* possible in limited cases, so long as you can somehow fool the typechecker for just long enough to get your code generated, which is the trick I pulled with my [Autoproxy 'lite' plugin](https://github.com/kevinwright/Autoproxy-Lite).  Even then, you're far better off working with `TreeDSL` to generate code instead of pumping out raw source.

Comment: So you can generate "code" as AST which the compiler will treat properly?

Comment: TreeDSL makes it very easy to achieve much the same effect as writing code.  But be aware of the issues surrounding class/method synthesis and how this can't be done after type checking.

Comment: Are there conceptual reasons not to allow plugins to issue actions of the kind "Forget name/type analysis result and redo", or is it just not implemented?

Comment: Internally, the compiler uses a mutable symbol table that's shared between units.  I did try a technique or running an "early" typer (with suppressed errors) before the plugin.  Unfortunately though, this left the symbol table in an inconsistent state.  I remember that class/singleton companions were especially tricky here.

Answer (score 1):

Kevin is entirely correct, but just for completeness it's worth mentioning that there is another alternative - write a compiler plugin that generates source. This is the approach that I've adopted in [Borachio](http://www.paulbutcher.com/2011/07/power-mocking-in-scala-with-borachio/). It's not a very satisfactory solution, but it can be made to work.

**Edit - I just reread your question and realised that you're actually asking about generating source anyway**

So there is no support for this directly, but it's basically just a question of opening a file and writing the relevant "print" statements. There's no way to invoke the compiler "inside" a plugin AFAIK, but I've written an [sbt plugin](https://github.com/paulbutcher/borachio-sbt-plugin) which hides most of the complexity of invoking the compiler twice.

Comment: Now I get it. It wasn't a "compiler plugin", but an "sbt plugin". I suppose it could be an ant or maven plugin instead, but the point is that it cannot be a compiler plugin, so I still can't do it like that.